# Can't get hibernate to work Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: hibernate

I followed the usual tutorials. swapfile size => UUID / offset => grub / initramfs (+update both) ([tutorial](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html))
But it seems that the hibernate function doesn't work.

When I run

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

The screen display glitches and then the computer shuts down. When I reboot, it's like any start up, the session wasn't saved.
Hibernate does work on Windows on the same computer.
Is it still an issue in Ubuntu 21.10 or did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not configured at all by default.
You may want to follow the [instructions here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html)

Basically, you will need to:

1. Create swap file (so memory can be saved there on disk)
2. Update grab so Ubuntu will load from that file

It did work for me after I completed it.